# How can I add push notifications to a ReactJS web app created using Vite?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, vite

I'm currently working on a real-time chat application using ReactJS (version 18.2) and Firebase SDK (version 9.7, modular), and I want to add push notifications to the web version of the app. I have already implemented push notifications using FCM in the React Native version of the app, but I'm struggling to find a way to add them to the ReactJS web app created using Vite. I would appreciate any guidance or assistance on how to accomplish this task. Thank you in advance for your help!

i have tried all methods that are available on google  like creating  "firebase-messaging-sw.js"

Comment: Without seeing [what you already tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's unlikely that someone can explain this better than the Firebase documentation on [setting up FCM in a web client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client) or one of the many tutorials out there already do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I apologize, everything was fine, but my operating system's notification software is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Import the necessary Firebase modules
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging, getToken } from "firebase/messaging";

// Configure Firebase with your credentials
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***************",
    authDomain: "***************",
    projectId: "***************",
    storageBucket: "***************",
    messagingSenderId: "***************",
    appId: "***************:web:***************",
    measurementId: "***************"
};

// Initialize the Firebase app
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = getMessaging(app);

// Get the messaging token
getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: '***************' })
    .then((currentToken) => {
        if (currentToken) {
            console.log(currentToken, "currentToken");
        } else {
            console.log("currentToken error");
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error getting messaging token:", error);
    });

// Request permission for notifications
function requestPermission() {
    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        if (permission === 'granted') {
            console.log('Notification permission granted...');
        } else {
            console.log("Do not have permissions");
        }
    });
}

requestPermission();
//got same error in react vite app
```